# C# Back color on text in a RichTextBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, richtextbox, fixed-width

I've created a Windows Form App that reads in a fixed-width text file, gets the width of the columns from user input, then uses that to display the different columns on screen with different text colours. It works fine that way.

But, it doesn't work if the field is blank - which in the text files that I'm using, they sometimes are; but I still want them to be defined. So I thought the best way to do it would be to put a back color on it, like this:

http://tinypic.com/r/2ic38sm/7

But I can't find how to do it with a RichTextBox - Is it possible? And if not, is there any way I could do it in a Windows form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't there a Selection.BackColor property on the richTextBox?

Wouldn't a GridView or ListView with Details View be a better control for your problem?

Comment: Oh, I thought that was the back color of the control... No?

Comment: Nope.  Because it has "Selection" in it: "SelectionBackColor."  I still think that you ought to be using a different control for your particular application.

Comment: Maybe, but I want it to be displayed as it is in the file, just with back color. I thought a RTB would be the best...

Comment: @New Start: Perhaps, if you can draw on top of the RTB, and if you use a fixed-width font, you could also draw vertical lines to delineate the columns and make it better-looking.  I've never done anything like this, though.... I take it back, I think that'd be too complicated.  There's font widths to deal with, and that gets nasty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectAll();
RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

If you are looking at changing the colours of the text, then you can use:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Here is a useful link:  [RichTextBox Tips](http://www.dotnetperls.com/richtextbox)

Taken from the link above:

```
richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Consolas", 18f, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
string[] words =
{
    "Dot",
    "Net",
    "Perls",
    "is",
    "a",
    "nice",
    "website."
};
Color[] colors =
{
    Color.Aqua,
    Color.CadetBlue,
    Color.Cornsilk,
    Color.Gold,
    Color.HotPink,
    Color.Lavender,
    Color.Moccasin
};

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    string word = words[i];
    Color color = colors[i];
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = color;
        richTextBox1.AppendText(word);
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        richTextBox1.AppendText(" ");
    }
}
```